# Primary keys MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have seen it said that I should have a primary key for all tables in an SQL database. However, I've created a database with a number of tables that are just used for storing the ID of another attribute that belongs to the first. In both cases, I will need multiple mentions of each ID, so what, if anything, should I use for the primary key?

Comment: Columns in one table that reference Primary Key columns in another table are called Foreign Keys.
A table that contains many of these Foreign Keys can itself have it's own Primary Key column. Just set it up like you set-up your primary keys in other tables (e.g. use an auto-incrementing column).

Comment: Why would you want duplicate rows in your table? Quite simply duplicate data is something you should avoid and therefore you should declare a key on the column(s) to be unique. Adding an arbitrary surrogate key has nothing to do with it because that obviously won't prevent the original data from being duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to go if I get what you are saying

Primary keys can be compound

eg. CustomerContacts could have CustomnerID and ContactID, with a primary key of both columns

so you could have

```
1,1
1,2
2,2
2,3
```

but you couldn't have another Customer2 linked to Contact2

The other way would be a surrogate, usually an auto increement

```
CustomerContacts
CustomerContactID, CustomerID, ContactID, now you could have
1,2,2
2,2,2
```

which you may or may not want.

Choose the one you want, because what you've seen said is very true, without a unique key, aside from poetntially suffering a good stick of performance problems you get the "some other user has changed a record problem"

So say you had a tables of Names, and Tony is in it twice.
You want to delete one of them, how does the DBMS identify which Tony has to go?
It will either get rid of both, or it will get really upset and throw it's toys out of the pram.

If it hasn't got a unique key, it has failed 1st normal form, that means you can kiss goodbye to all the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I think the surrogate is the way to go here.

Comment: In general I always plump for surrogates over compound keys, but that's more of an aesthetic, than a this is the "right" way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can just use a column 'id' as a primary key to keep track of the row number. For the stored attribute, you can have the column named 'stored_attribute_id'

Comment: Is there actually any benefit to keeping track of the row number in this case though? There is no circumstance under which I'll be selecting this attributes through the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear. A Primary Key defines a combination of columns which, for that table, you are defining must be unique. If the entry is contained in another table you may want to investigate [Foreign Keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: In an attempt to place my database in 2NF I'm separating out foreign keys in one table into a separate table for these attributes, to prevent blank columns. Essentially, I'm just creating a new table using only foreign keys. I don't know if this is good practice, but this is the best fix I could come up with.

Comment: If you're not sure, you could look at this http://www-home.htwg-konstanz.de/~waesch/DBResearch/content/dbnormalizer.htm  That can normalize your proposed table and identify keys for you

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I believe I'll just add another column with an arbitrary primary key.